# Access Wordpress plugin's template methods

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and trying to learn my way through Wordpress. Within my theme's functions.php file, I wanted to access a method available inside bbPress's plugin template.php file. I'm getting `"Unexpected token ['`

Inside bbPress plugin template.php:

```
function bbp_topic_reply_count( $topic_id = 0, $integer = false ) {
    echo bbp_get_topic_reply_count( $topic_id, $integer );
}
```

I'm accessing this function in my current theme's functions.php:

```
$count = bbp_topic_reply_count(125);
```

Do I have to include anything from the plugin (i.e bbpress/template.php)? What's the proper way to access these template methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was because of the "echo" statement which is not handled in my functions.php

Calling bbp_get_topic_reply_count() solved my problem.